# Почему необходимо указать doubleValue (без него не выполняется), ведь автораспарковка должна сработать?

Tags: java

```
package main;

public class alfa <pablo extends Number> {

pablo[] nums;

alfa (pablo[] o) {

    nums=o;
}

   double average() {

        double sum = 0.0;
        for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
        sum += nums[i].doubleValue();
        }
        return sum/nums.length;
   }

   public static void main (String[] args) {  

       Integer inums[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
       alfa <Integer> alo = new alfa <Integer>(inums);

       double v = alo.average();

       System.out.println("Znacenie : " + v);    
   }
}
```

Comment: Почитайте, пожалуйста, Java Code Conventions. Имена классов должны писаться с большой буквы. Это поможет другим людям лучше понимать ваш код.

Answer (score 2):

Автораспаковка работает только так

```
Integer iOb = 100; // автоматически упаковывает значение типа int
int i = iOb; // автораспаковка
```

И тоже самое для остальных типов.

Преобразовать между Integer и double нельзя

```
int     a = 1;
Integer b = 1;

double  c = (double) a;   // OK
Double  d = (Double) b;   // NOT ON.
```

Вы задаете требование для pablo быть Number. И вы можете считывать только через метод doubleValue, так как шаблонный класс alfa может быть объявлен с любым типом унаследованным от Number.

Answer (score 1):

Автоматически распаковаться в `double` может только `java.lang.Double`. А у вас какие-то `pablo` в массиве хранятся...